# Macbook silently disconnects from Comcast home router, what is happening and how can I fix it?

Tags: internet, wireless-router, macbook

I have a MacBook Pro, connected to a Comcast Router.  Symptom: every page times out, can't ping anything.  Computer still thinks it's connected to the internet.  Can access router home at 10.0.0.1, but cannot access LAN devices or anything online.

Due to teleworking, I am holed up at my fiance's with a Comcast router and company-issued Macbook from 2017(which I may use for both work and play).  At least once every hour or two, usually every 10-20 minutes (on rare occasion every 5 minutes) web sites stop loading, I get booted from the LAN minecraft server, etc.  Most of the time I do not notice when it occurs, because I spend most of my time on local work (all the databases are local copies, and I work on local deployments of websites and apis).

When this occurs, I can still access 10.0.0.1 (the home ip) and see the list of connected devices.  My computer thinks it is still connected to the internet.  Going anywhere in Chrome, instead of showing the no-internet dinosaur, times out.  Google Docs is stuck in 'Saving...' forever.  `git fetch` runs until I ctrl+c.  Then I turn my internet off (and everything suddenly realizes I have no connection.  Dinosaur running game.  Every request fails immediately) and then I turn it back on.  It takes about 10 seconds, and then everything loads again.  Running `ifconfig | grep 10.0` (to get my computer's ip address) returns the same address before, during, and after the outage.  `ifconfig` seems to remain the same regardless of whether or not I'm connected.

The list of connected devices at 10.0.0.1 only has 11 devices, which surprises me greatly.  (My household of 5 people usually has 30+ devices.  Her household also has 5 people, including me).  Perhaps that's only devices that are turned on, though.  The problem does seem to get worse later in the night.  But I don't think it's due to peak hours, as the worst I've seen it (less than 5 minutes apart) was when we were playing Minecraft at 1:30am.

No other devices have this issue (besides my GalaxyS8 cell phone, which disconnects maybe once or twice a day).  The TV, other phones, other computers, and video game consoles all are completely stable.  My computer has never had this problem at my house (AT&T) or at my office (provider unknown to me, but it's a business router).  Due to the lockdown, I cannot test my computer against other connections right now.  It started as soon as I came here for the lockdown.  I have not previously worked from this LAN.  My cell phone has had the same level of problem on other networks (but again, it's maybe twice a day that I have to toggle wifi off and on).

Can anyone tell me what's going on and how I can fix it?

## More Info

The DNS servers listed under Mac Settings -> Network -> Advanced -> DNS are `75.75.75.75`, `75.75.76.76`, `2001:558:feed::1`, and `2001:558:feed::2`

I am currently trying what is listed here: [Windows 7 repeatedly disconnects from only one specific router](https://superuser.com/questions/782620/windows-7-repeatedly-disconnects-from-only-one-specific-router), except instead of using Google's DNS servers, I am using option #1 from https://www.techradar.com/news/best-dns-server, and using OpenDNS at addresses `208.67.222.222` and `208.67.220.220`.  If I go the entirety of tomorrow, without a single disconnect, (and possibly play on Minecraft multiplayer without the connection closing), then I will consider this resolved.

## Update

I ran into the bug again the day after changing my DNS servers.  I believe I caught, very briefly, the loading bar at the bottom of Chrome saying "resolving host" before it went kaput.  So... back to square one?

Comment: I'm glad I asked this question here, and not on askdifferent, especially if the DNS thing actually works.

Comment: Does the problem continue if you change DNS servers, say to Google's open servers 8..8.8 and 8.8.4.4 (IPv6 2001:4860:4860::8888 and 2001:4860:4860::8844), or Cloudflare's at 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1 (IPv6  2606:4700:4700::1111,2606:4700:4700::1001 )?

Comment: "Does the problem continue" -> Will determine this by end of day tomorrow.

Comment: "Does the problem continue" Yes, yes it does.  I switched to OpenDNS and it still breaks.  Do I need to specify the IPv6 as well as IPv4?  Or can I just use the IPv4 ones?

Comment: I'm currently testing using CloudFlare and using all four servers you listed.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no difference.  I still get disconnected.